Fantasy book where the female main character fights evil and she is an orphan
So, I don’t remember much, but this what we have:

This is a fantasy with a little bit of spicy.
The female main character fights evil and she is an orphan.
Somehow she has a little evil creature living in her house with whom she is friends.
In their world, the evil spirits — she fights — often throw their children to other people (foundlings), these children can be identified by the fact that when you wound them with a special metal or stone, their blood boils.
the main character did not know until the very end of the book that she was the child thrown into their world by evil spirits
The book ends with a scene where the main character is already at home, recovering from a wound in battle, and she goes and cuts her hand with a metal or stone and her blood boils
book was published before 2017


Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this a physical book or an e-book?  Do you recall the cover art?

Hi! I’ve read e-book copy. And I really don’t remember how look cover
